# Minecraft server use all CPU

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to create a private minecraft server (on 1.17.1) on my raspberry PI 4-b with 8 GB of RAM.

I have install Ubuntu server 64 bit and openJDK 17 but actually when I start my server it reply me after few seconds.

> Can't keep up ! Is the server overloaded ? ...

And also I check the procces with htop and I can see that minecraft take minimum around 30 threads and use all my CPU (400%) so I tried to limit the number of thread but that dosent work's ...  Anyone know what can I do to optimise my minecraft server please ?

Also my shell script for starting my minecraft server :

```
java -jar -server -Xmx4G -Xms1024M -XX:CICompilerCount=4 server.jar nogui
```

Also, this is my [timings](https://timings.spigotmc.org/?url=opaqajisuj) :

```
 Pct Total  Pct Tick       Total             Avg     PerTick      Count     Event
  24.99%      24.90%     83.62 s        12.45 ms     1.0           6.7k     world - doTick
  19.14%      19.07%     64.03 s         9.54 ms     1.0           6.7k     world - tickEntities
   6.01%       5.99%     20.10 s         2.99 ms     1.0           6.7k     world_nether - doTick
   4.41%       4.39%     14.74 s         2.19 ms     1.0           6.7k     world_the_end - doTick
   1.39%    9,303.90%     4.65 s     4,651.95 ms     0.0           0.0k     World Save
   0.44%       0.43%      1.46 s         0.22 ms     1.0           6.7k     world_nether - tickEntities
   0.42%       0.41%      1.39 s         0.21 ms     1.0           6.7k     world - tracker
   0.20%       0.20%      0.68 s         0.10 ms     1.0           6.7k     world_the_end - tickEntities
   0.10%       0.10%      0.32 s         0.05 ms     1.0           6.7k     world_nether - tracker
   0.03%       0.03%      0.11 s         0.02 ms     1.0           6.7k     world_the_end - tracker
```

Comment: Can you do a timing with `/timings on` then (few mins after) `timings paste` ?

Comment: Also, about "do you have any idea where i can ask my question ?" there is [spigot.org](https://www.spigotmc.org/), on their [discord](https://www.spigotmc.org/link-forums/discord.95/). You can also download plugin to manage which plugin take which perfs, but it show it real-time (contrary to timings). Finally, you can ask it on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (other site of SO community, about video games)

Comment: I Don't know how tu use the timings commands ... minecraft don't reconize this command and i find a binary timing but i don't know how to use it

Comment: Do `/timings on`. Then wait few minutes, to make the server get data to inspect what take resources. Then, I think around 10/15 minutes (try to wait until lag) you do `/timings paste` that will give you a link. I need this link to help you to tell you what is the issue exactly

Comment: Ok so i did the command , it tooks time cause it only work on spigot server and i was on bukkit ... but here is the link : https://www.spigotmc.org/go/timings?url=opaqajisuj

Comment: Ok, so now you are on spigot 1.17 ? And bukkit it's pretty fine, paperspigot or spigot are clearly better

Comment: Yes i'm on spigot 1.17.1 server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [your timings](https://timings.spigotmc.org/?url=opaqajisuj) of your server, there is this line :

```
1.39%   9,303.90%     4.65 s     4,651.95 ms     0.0           0.0k     World Save
```

It represent the majority of your issue. Such as it's not because of:

- plugin: can't fix it quickly (by reporting it to plugin owner/deleting it)
- Not bukkit event issue
- Not ticking entity (too many entity)
- Too much RAM

Such as it's because of save, what can create this issue:

- **RAM**: 8Go can take over 50 players (plugins included), so clearly no.
- **Java**: JDK 17 is latest so it's difficult to have so several issue I don't think
- **CPU**: You talk about this. It's possible, but such as it can run on this type of product, it should not be this, and not over 9k%.
- **Storage**: I think you have bad storage. It's not SSD so your entiere server are waiting for the save of it. It can be prooved with [this thread](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/349405/) on spigotmc.

#### How can you fix it ?

That's clearly difficult **without buying a new storage**.

You can try to never save except when there isn't any player for example.

You can also try to reduce all feature that can produce storage save:

- Upgrade **autosave** (in `bukkit.yml`)
- **Render distance** (in `server.properties`)
- Upgrade **despawn** of item, arrow... (in `spigot.yml`)
- Downgrade **spawn limits** (in `bukkit.yml`)

Comment: @OP You're going to be hard-pressed to run a server on a raspberry pi 4-b, you would need to reduce some of the default settings (chunk render distance, for instance). The timings support the issue being storage, but the actual CPU may only support in the ballpark of 5 players. Chunk rendering is one of the most expensive operations in minecraft

Comment: Yes but when the server is loaded in RAM, then player doesn't load lot of chunk (thanks elytra for example) it's fine. Here the save take everything, so maybe he can keep resource with render distance, but the sotrage seems more important

Comment: The world renderer will not keep all chunks (or any specific chunks) loaded in memory by default. As a player moves around, new chunks are loaded, and old ones saved to the disk. You're correct in stating it's storage, but it's not the only bottleneck being faced here.

Comment: I just edit my answer to add more informations about this. For me, even if yes render distance can create issue, even if we set it as 1 we will have issue so just with changing storage will make the server be able to have better settings

Comment: I think I'm not managing to communicate my overall point: even with changing the storage, it won't really be enough. My suggestion is to honestly ditch using the pi and run it on your own machine, unless using the pi is some form of personal challenge. Setting render distance too low would have a different type of drawback (hastily reading/writing chunks while moving), and thus cannot be set lower than `3` anyhow.

Comment: effectively ! you are a genious ! 
So i disabled the Autosave in bukkit.yml
(autosave: -1) 
And i don't have any error anymore so it should be that ... thanks for your help now I suppose I have to find how I can backup my server without create any issue but it should be fine ;)

Comment: You can save it with `/save-all` :) (it will freeze/rollback everyone for few seconds, until end of save) Also, if the answer fix your issue, you can accept it with check mark ;)